# JS Sort - Determine if Anything Changed?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm using array.sort to sort an array of objects.

Is there someway to determine if the order of those objects changed other than doing a comparison myself?  Some in-built JS function?  I don't need to know the # of changes, just that there was at least 1 change.

**Update:**

I'm sorting custom objects, e.g.:

```
[
 { 'value' : 5, 'name' : 'foo'},
 { 'value' : 3, 'name' : 'bar'},
 { 'value' : 10, 'name' : 'js'}
]
```

**Update 2:**

I'm considering adding an additional custom property 'order' as I generate the objects and then checking to see if 'order' is or isn't sequential after the .sort.  Is there a faster/better method?

Comment: So you want to know if they weren't in order when you called sort?

Comment: what kind of objects are you sorting? having control over them will be nice and efficient if the changing objects could signal the array as dirty or fire the sort themselves

Comment: Yes, if you care about performance, track when and how the array is actually changed.

Comment: But changing the array does not necessarily change the sort order.

Comment: @neu-rah - see my updates.  Yes, I have control over them.  Could you elaborate on your idea?

Comment: ok, i updated my response also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to mess with two copies of the array, check the array before starting the sort.

You can loop through the array and return true if every item is in its sorted position, 
(compares 'less' than the next item) or false as soon as one item is detected in the wrong position.

Since you are using objects, the comparison code depends on the way you are sorting the objects.

Comment: See my updates... Update 2 is basically what you suggest.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing built in that does what you are asking. If it is a simple array you can just use join/toString() and compare the two final strings. If the array contains objects, probably would use JSON.stringify and compare.

```
var myArray1 = [1,2,3,4,5],
    myArray2 = [2,1,3,4,5],
    myArray1_sorted = myArray1.slice().sort(),
    myArray2_sorted = myArray2.slice().sort();

//Check to see if the strings are the same or different
console.log( myArray1_sorted.toString() === myArray1.toString() ); //true - sort should not change anything
console.log( myArray2_sorted.toString() === myArray2.toString() ); //false - sort should have changed order
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) docs:

```
array.sort([compareFunction])
```

So it is obvious, there is no built-in solution/method for detecting whether at least one element has changed its position during the sorting. So you need to write your own method:

```
function isAnyElementChangedItsPosition( unsortedArray, sortedArray ){
   for( var i = 0; i < unsortedArray.length; ++i){
       if( unsortedArray[i] !== sortedArray[i] ){
           return true;
       }
   } 
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to compare the arrays somehow. You can easily clone an array and make the check:

```
  var arr = [5, 4, 1, 6]
  var arrBefore = arr.slice(0);
  arr.sort()

  for(var i =0; i< arr.length; i++) { 
    if (arrBefore[i] !== arr[i]) {
      // a change was made
    }
  }
```

Comment: this duplicates data, we need only to compare the order i[n]<i[n+1] (or a variant of this)

Answer (score 0):

In short: no built-in function, you've gotta check for equality.

Here's one way to check for equality:

```
function arraysEqual(a, b) {

    // Are the lengths the same?
    var i = a.length;
    if (i !== b.length)
        return false;

    // Are all the values the same?
    while (i --) {
        if (a[i] !== b[i])
            return false;
    }

}
```

Note that this *doesn't* check if they're arrays; `arraysEqual("abc", ["a", "b", "c"])` is true. You can add this check if you want.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a built-in function to do what you want.

How about this:

```
function isArraySorted(array) {
    if (!array.length) {
        return true;
    }
    var lastElement = array[0];
    for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] <= lastElement) {
            return false;
        }
        lastElement = array[i];
    }
    return true;
}

alert(isArraySorted([1,2,3]) + " " + isArraySorted([1,2,3,2.5]));

var array = [1,2,3];

if (!isArraySorted(array)) {
    // No need to do the sort if the array is already sorted.
    array.sort();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not duplicating data, becase strings and parallel arrays do.

```
function chkOrder(a) {
  for(var i =1; i< a.length; i++)
    if (a[i-1] > a[i]) return false;
  return true;
}
```

you might need to work on th ">" sign if you reverse the order
this will also return false (not ordered) on first occourence

if we can control the contained objects then we can control changes in the objects and fire a parent sort

```
function O(parent,data) {//initialize with parent and value array/object
  this.parent=parent;
  this.data=data;
  //shortcurt to sort parent
  this.sort=function()
    {console.log("sortingparent");this.parent.sort(this.parent.sortfunc);}
  this.setData=function(data) {
  this.data=data;
  this.sort();
}
//if changes can be groupped then is more efficient to signal parent dirty and sort latter
this.setKey=function(key,value) {//change value in the data
  if (key==parent.sortkey&&value!=this.data[key]) {
    this.data[key]=value;
    this.sort();
  } else this.data[key]=value;
}
this.parent.push(this);
  this.sort();
  return this;
}
//-------
//using a simple array, this could also be and object and have specific func's
var arr=[];
//example, sort by name, ascending
arr.sortkey="name";
//closure to build a sort predicate bound to the used key
function setkey(key) {return function(a,b) {return a.data[key]>b.data[key];}}
arr.sortfunc=setkey(arr.sortkey);
var b=new O(arr,{name:"B",value:0});
var c=new O(arr,{name:"C",value:2});
var a=new O(arr,{name:"A",value:1});
var d=new O(arr,{name:"D",value:3});
console.log("changing value");
a.setKey("value",100);//when not sorting by value its the same as a.data.value=100
console.log("changing name");
a.setKey("name","X");//this will fire parent sort
for(n=0;n<arr.length;n++) console.log(arr[n].data.name,"=",arr[n].data.value);
```

Comment: sorry about O.setKey function used to change data values is "ambiguous" with the global setKey that has a complete distinct functionality... fell free to name the methods

Comment: and yes there is something in JS that can help you with the task, there is getters and setters as http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/ even if they wont give a direct answer about the sort, they can be hooked on every element value so that you don't have to use that O.setKey function to change values. They can be hooked to values and do a similar check with the advantage of making change values transparent while "secretly" checking order changes.

Answer (score -1):

```
var data = [
    { 'value' : 5, 'name' : 'foo'},
    { 'value' : 3, 'name' : 'bar'},
    { 'value' : 10, 'name' : 'js'}
];

var changed = sortAndReport(data, byValue);

// sortAndReport :: [a], (a, a -> Number) -> Boolean
// Sorts an array according to the provided Array.prototype.sort
// compare function and returns a Boolean indicating whether
// sorting changed the order of the array.
function sortAndReport(a, fn) {
    var changed = false;

    a.sort(function (a, b) {
        var sortResult = fn(a, b);
        changed        = sortResult > 0;
        return sortResult;
    });

    return changed;
}

// byValue :: { value :: Number }, { value :: Number } -> Number
function byValue(a, b) {
    return a.value - b.value;
}
```

Comment: sort() shouldn't alter the length by default. This code also doesn't execute anything in the `if` block, because why would it?

Comment: well those are 2 code blocks... so they will execute eventually because there will be code in between (obvious).. but still they only check length

Comment: Adjusted the code to show that the two blocks were not intended to be contiguous.  This very simple suggestion does not imply that `.sort()` itself alters the length of the array.

Comment: This isn't my concern.  After sorting I potentially have to do DOM changes... but only if the order changed.  I don't want to do the DOM changes if I don't have to.